# add a php variable onto an url for cURL use

Tags: php, curl

I have a search box which is passing the user input into my cURL, to make the search on the webservice. I thought of adding the inputs (or variables) to the URL I'm using to connect to via cURL.
However I think I'm doing it wrong.
The hostname was removed on purpose for the post.

```
// Specify the URL to connect to - this can be PHP, HTML or anything else!
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "https://WebService.php?aRegion='$aRc'&aType=empty");
```

I am suppossed to had something more besides the '..' when using a php variable into a link right?

Answer (score 1):

That URL you currently use does not really make sense...

1. issue: you forgot to specify a host name. Without such the http client tries to resolve `hWebService.php` via the domain name resolution which will fail since that is *not* a valid host name.
2. you are using invalid characters in your URL.

Here is an approach that should be close to what you finally need, is easy to read (that *is* important!) and also takes care of url encoding the variable values:

```
curl_setopt(
    $connection, 
    CURLOPT_URL, 
    sprintf(
        "https://example.com/hWebService.php?aRegion=%s&aType=empty", 
        urlencode($aRc)));
```

Note: "example.com" obviously is only an example.

---

Update: you ask how to inject the value of a second variable as `aType` get parameter. Here the modified version:

```
curl_setopt(
    $connection, 
    CURLOPT_URL, 
    sprintf(
        "https://example.com/hWebService.php?aRegion=%s&aType=%s", 
        urlencode($aRc), 
        urlencode($aType)));
```

Comment: Made it work thanks to this, Thanks! Just another quick question, how do I do it when the aType no longer as the value of "empty" but is a variable instead?

Comment: Well, it is an obvious modification you need to make for the second variable. I updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're getting at or the process you're taking to get the information but you could try this.

```
$user_input1 = $_GET['information_you_need_to_append_to_curl'];

$user_input2 = $_GET['other_user_info'];

$web_address = sprint_f("https://WebService.php?aRegion=%s&aType=%s", $user_input1, $user_input2);

curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $web_address);
```

This will retrieve information from a get request made to your PHP document and then add it to your web address at the end of your curl request.

Check out the php documentation for more information on the sprint_f function